# How do I find pandas rows with a pattern

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]

As you can see, I have made a dataframe called df and have got the first 7 rows with specific columns that I specified. Right now though, I want to get every other row. like rows 1,3,5,7 or  2,4,6. The code I have done so far is also in blockquote.

```
df.iloc[:, np.r_[0:3, 6:10, 10:14]].head(7)
```

Also I want to know if this is similar to every three rows and so on. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you mean `df.iloc[::2]`?

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: @wwii Ok thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [slicing method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html)

Something like `df[::n]` where `n = number of rows`

So assuming the dataframe is `df`, and you want every other row, you could do `new_df = df[::2]`, if you want every 3 rows, it would be `new_df = df[::3]` etc.

Alternatively, assuming your data is indexed properly, you could also do something like:

`new_df = df[df.index % 3 != 0]`

which would give you 2 rows, skip the 3rd, 2 rows, skip the 3rd, etc. You can change the integer to decide how many to keep.

Comment: @SriswaroopKoundinya if this answers your question, please make sure to accept it.